# Android - Proper way to listen for variable change, and do something upon change?

Tags: android, variables, handler, listen

The app I'm making requires that a bit of code be executed whenever the value of a particular variable changes from 0 to 1.
The handler example below is the method I'm currently using to do this (I copied it from someone else).
I have a feeling it's not a proper method though because having just three of these handlers in my app causes the UI to be fairly unresponsive, and causes the device (a phone) to become quite hot.
As you can see, I've put 10ms delays in the handlers to try to deal with this.
Isn't there something more like **OnClickListener** that can listen at all times for a variable value change without putting such stress on the CPU?
I'm pretty new to Java and Android so a simple example would be very much appreciated.

```
  final Handler myHandler1 = new Handler();
  new Thread(new Runnable()
  {
  @Override
     public void run()
     {
        while (true)
        {
           try
           {
           Thread.sleep(10);
           myHandler1.post(new Runnable()
              {
              @Override
                 public void run() 
                 {
                    if (myVariable == 1)
                    {
                    myVariable = 0;
                    //do stuff
                    }   
                 }
              });
           } catch (Exception e) {}
        }
     }  
  }).start();
```

Comment: you can implement your delegate pattern if you need it. What's your issue

Comment: What is changing the value of the variable and how often does it happen? It seems like you need a `BroadcastReceiver`.

Comment: @Squonk Pressing either the enter key on the keyboard or a button on the screen changes the value to 1. The frequency is determine by how often the user presses the key/button. Most likely, the value change will occur once per second max, but it's important that the value change be recognized and acted upon immediately so that the user doesn't see a delayed response.

Comment: @EricGlass : In that case I don't really see what your problem is. Why don't you just do what needs to be done in the key/button event handlers?

Comment: @Squonk In this particular case, I was trying to keep things nice & tidy, and was trying to help ensure that two instances of the process couldn't be launched simultaneously by pressing both the enter key and the on-screen button at the same time. But this was mostly just an example for you. I've recently come across several situations in which having the ability to 'listen' to the variable would have been ideal. At the moment, more than trying to solve a particular problem, I'm just looking for an answer to the question I asked, for the sake of knowledge & future reference.

Answer (score 1):

You must set your variable via a setter method. Then, you can be reactive to that change.

```
public void setMyVariable(int value) {
this.myVariable = value;
if (myVariable == 1) {
  doSomethingWhen1();
} else if (myVariable == 0) {
  doSomethingWhen0();
}
}
```

A more elegant way to do that will be an observer pattern, [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) you can find more detailed documentation about it.

You must certainly avoid `while(true)` loops on mobile device, it will drain your battery and you are also blocking the UI thread. That's the reason why your UI is unresponsive and your cellphone it's quite hot.

Comment: I can't get this to work. The app behaves as though I never even inserted it :( ... Do I leave the word "value" or do I replace that with something?

Comment: I think I figured it out. I'm supposed to use this: setMyVariable(1); to call to this thing. Pretty different from what I need but at least now I know how to call to something. Thanks for the info about while(true) ... very good to know.